# number system and divisibility

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, prime-factorization

could anyone please find a solution to that problem:

$b$,$c$,$d$ are consecutive even integers such that $2\lt b \lt c \lt d$. what is the largest positive integer that MUST be a divisor of $bcd$?

Comment: What "such that 2" mean? All three are even, at least one of them is a multiple of 4, and one of them is a multiple of 3, so 48 must be a divisor. That is obviously best possible. But if you want to prove it, you need to find two examples which have no other common factor.

Comment: What is "such that 2." supposed to mean?

Comment: sorry guys, edited. the symbols were hidden.

Comment: You should add that you are searching for the largest integer that divides ANY b,c,d with the given constraints. Otherwise it leads to confusion as can be seen in the comments to almagests answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least one of the numbers is even and at least one is a multiple of 4. Also one is a multiple of 3. So the product must be divisible by 48. Take $b=4,c=6,d=8$ then the product is 192=48\times4. Take $b=10,c=12,d=14$, then the product is $1680=48\times 35$. They have greatest common factor 48, so 48 is the best possible result.

Comment: thanks for your answer. just one confusion, `bcd` must be even number, so it will be divisible by `(bcd)/2`, and should be largest possible number.is my reasoning correct?

Comment: With this thought why don't you take directly $bcd$? Cause $bcd$ divdies $bcd$. But you can't take something that depends on $b$, $c$ or $d$ because you can take them as big as you want so it won't work for other little ones like $b=4,c=6,d=8$

Comment: Yes. It is even, so $bcd/2$ is a factor. But you cannot guarantee that that $bcd/2$ will be factor for different values of $b$.